# Снять выделение(contenteditable="true")

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

http://jsfiddle.net/HFGSd/

Выделите слово "текст" и нажмите "Выделить текст". Добавятся теги <b></b> к слову "текст".
Так же сделал кнопку Удалить выделение, но работает она совсем плохо. Если выделить выделенное слово "текст" и нажать на кнопку "Удалить выделение", то всё удалится. А вот если например из выделенного текста, выделить только букву "т" и нажать "Удалить выделение", то естественно буква "т" останется выделенной, а нужно, чтобы снялось выделение.

За удаление отвечает функция `wrapSelectedRemove`.
Наверно просто я делаю что-то не так.

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто сможет. Последняя проблема )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectedText = selection.extractContents();

// удаляем теги
var tags_text = selectedText.textContent.replace(new RegExp(open+close, 'gi'), '');

selection.insertNode(document.createTextNode(tags_text));
```

Если же тебе нужно чтобы при выделении мышкой части области в определенном теге очищались эти теги, то тут нужно уже думать.

Comment: @lampa, угу, как раз нужно именно это: Если же тебе нужно чтобы при выделении мышкой части области в определенном теге очищались эти теги, то тут нужно уже думать.

Мне хотябы алгоритм реализации, а дальше я уже сам.

Comment: @ModaL: А чем не устраивает использование [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla)? Есть и выделение текста и удаления формата в выделенной области.

Comment: А я хочу свое, и все равно, что велосипед. Зато хоть как-то сам делал.

Comment: Заюзал уж document.execCommand, в нём всё просто. А то уже целый день убил на это.

Comment: @ModaL так-то мне кажется нужно было бы искать позицию выделенного слова в тексте, потом от этой позиции начинать в разные стороны поиск тегов.